# Get paths of minimum MSE python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of list of vectors.

```
[
 [[1,2,3],[7,8,5]],
 [[7,8,9],[2,8,6],[2,6,3]],
 [[7,5,1],[1,7,3],[6,1,1],[5,2,7]]
]
```

For each of the vectors in the first list , I want to extract the path of minimum distance (MSE) across vectors in each list.

For example, for the first element in the first list, I should obtain this path:

```
[1,2,3] -> [2,6,3] -> [1,7,3]
```

in terms of indexes:

```
[0,2,1]
```

I should obtain this path for each element in the first list. The lists are huge and the real vectors are of about 300 elements.

There is some pythonic method that avoids hard iterating with for loops?

Comment: do all vectors have a fixed length?

Comment: Sorry for the misread. However, I don't think there's any possibility to avoid looping - looping is O(n) and any sort will boost it above that. But (if you're not looking for the traveling salesman solution), this is only O(m*n) which should be quite fast.

Comment: Can you post your solution which features the "hard iterating" which you want to avoid?

Comment: @Rock Li  I know that.  But maybe there are some useful one liners that keep minimums in permutations  between graph layers in python.  I am asking for a pythonic way to implement this particular graph search.  Thanks!

Comment: One liners are not avoiding the looping - it's very easy to turn a loop into a comprehension but that does not improve the algorithm at all - is that what you desire?

Comment: Yes,  the point is that I want comprehend at maximum without adding complexity.

Answer (score 0):

My algorithms knowledge is a little limited. I dont think there is any particular python specific best method for this. The comment Rock LI made is accurate. Theres a million dollar prize if you can find a best method to this. Implement a Dijkstra algorithm or whatever your favorite search method is for this. You can auto calculate weights from one list to the next. beyond that its pure algorithms

Comment: why is this posted as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: This is not the traveling salesman problem, OP is looking for the shortest path from one element of the first list of vectors to an element of the last one. He doesn't say he wants to visit them all.

Comment: This should have been a comment. I realized it after i posted it.